# Delete multiple mysql rows with check box not working

Tags: php, mysql

Here Is my problem: I do not get any error with my code but my problem is when i click the 'Delete Multiple' Button it does nothing not even reload the page.

Note: By The Way the `redirect_to();` function i created so do not get confused by thinking that is a php function or anything

PHP Code:

```
 display_errors(E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST['muldelete'])) {
$mul = $_POST['checkdelete'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM cmarkers WHERE id = " . $mul;
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
redirect_to("elerts.php");
}
```

HTML Code:

```
 <form action="elerts.php" method="post">
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
  <td> </td>
      <td>Date</td>
  <td>Comment</td>
  <td>Actions</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM cmarkers";
      $result = $db->query($sql);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkdelete[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['comment']; ?></td>
  <td><a href="delete_elert.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a><a href="edit_elert.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Edit</a></td>
  </tr>


  <?php 
  }
  ?>
  <input type="submit" name="muldelete" value="Delete Multiple" />
</table>
</form>
```

Thank You

If you need more info please let me know

Comment: Your submit button needs to be in a form in order to trigger the form action.

Comment: It doesn't do anything because it's just a button sitting there outside any form.

Comment: so i need a submit button for each row? @Franco

Comment: did you try debug it? do you know how to use xdebug?

Comment: no @drupality i have never used it

Comment: @JackSmith check this: https://jtreminio.com/2012/07/xdebug-and-you-why-you-should-be-using-a-real-debugger/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because You are closing form tag earlier than submit button.
Try to put whole table into  and should work.

PHP should looks like

```
 display_errors(E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST['muldelete'])) {
$mul = implode(',',$_POST['checkdelete']);

$sql = "DELETE FROM cmarkers WHERE id IN(" . $mul.")";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
redirect_to("elerts.php");
}
```

Comment: @JackSmith becuase You are using <?php $row['id']; ?> try to use <?= $row['id']; ?> or <?php echo $row['id']; ?>

Comment: now it deletes but it only deletes one at a time @diaraf

Comment: @JackSmith yes, because You generate more than one checkbox with same name, just use <input type="checkbox" name="checkdelete[]"... and then in php $mul = implode(',',$_POST['checkdelete']); and also $sql = "DELETE FROM cmarkers WHERE id IN (" . $mul.")";

Comment: thank you please join my chat at: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97149/php-mysql-html-css-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 3):

First, your code contain some attention and placements errors.

- input between `<table>` outer of td's is incorrect.
- You can't make a multiple delete if you generate one form by value to
  delete.

Fix them.

**Getting Array of muldelete**

To all the checked inputs, you must add the array field symbol
to clusterize the name "muldelete" to a post array.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkdelete[]" value="<?php $row['id']; ?>" /></td>
```

**PHP side**

Now you can fetch whole deletion array, like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST["muldelete"]))
{
   $mul = join(',', $_POST['checkdelete']);

   // Using IN() to make only one query for all records instead of multiple
   // ex: IN(3, 4, 54, 8)
   $query = "DELETE FROM cmarkers WHERE id IN(".$mul.")";
   $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
   redirect_to("elerts.php");
}
```

**Security**

If ID's are integer value, you can prevent string injection into the sql query

```
$mul = array_map(function($id)
{
   return intval($id);
}, $mul);
```

Comment: thank you please join my chat at: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97149/php-mysql-html-css-javascript-jquery

Comment: please go to the chat i sent thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Your button is outside the `<form></form>` tags, so it is not related to the form elements or the form method at all. Instead of having a different form for each checkbox you should surround the entire table with the form tags thus ensuring that all the checkboxes and the button are in the same form.

```
<form method='post' action='elerts.php'>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        ...all your table data including checkboxes...
        <input type="submit" name="muldelete" value="Delete Multiple" />
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Does the page now refresh when you hit the "Delete Multiple" button?

Comment: never mind diaraf help me you can come to my chat at: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97149/php-mysql-html-css-javascript-jquery

but thank you for your help

yes